# UIimage Detect Landscape Image with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uipickerviewcontroller

I want to read a photo from Library

in this function

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
```

now I want to know is that landscape photo or not I try to tie this code

```
if(pickedImage?.size.width > pickedImage?.size.height)
```

But I received this error **Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'CGFloat?' operands** how can I resolve this Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

   { 
      if pickedImage.size.width > pickedImage.size.height 
      {
         /// landscape mode
      }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here that you try to work with `Optional` values, instead of unwrapped. To unwrap value you can use `guard`:

```
guard let pickedImage = pickedImage else { 
    // false logic here
    return 
}

if pickedImage.size.height > pickedImage.size.height {

} else {

}
```

By the way, are you sure that you want to compare `pickedImage`'s height to itself? Looks weird.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution with this code ? -> !

```
if(pickedImage!.size.width > pickedImage!.size.height)
```

Comment: this is bad practice to use force unwrap (? -> !), because your app can crash.

Comment: @pacification yep he should avoid ! and use ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan, no. He should use `if let ...` or `guard let ...` to get result value.

Comment: this what I meant by ? sure it's a mirror to if let and guard

Comment: No, it's not true.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution could be to use switch pattern matching:

```
switch image?.size {
case .some(let size) where size.height > size.width:
  // do something
default:
  break
}
```